# Did flatbread originate in one place?

Tags: food

It is difficult to find a culture that does not have some form of flatbread. The Wikipedia [article provides a lengthy list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flatbread), listing types and locations.

Did flatbread first appear in one place and then spread to all of the others?

Comment: I suspect this is in the realm of prehistory.

Comment: According to Wikipedia, corn tortillas in the Americas predate European contact.  On that basis, the answer would be no.

Comment: Not sure we can rule out some knowledge of flatbread early enough that the Bering Strait was still passable, so perhaps tortillas could have come from Asia via Siberia.

Comment: @ Brian Drummond Except that maize didn't develop for thousands of years after leaving Asia, & I do not recall any early site finds of manos and metates or other means of grinding grain. SoCal natives ground acorns, but did not make flatbread, IIRC.